# Bug in Ruby RPG (skips line in case..when)

Tags: ruby, debugging, switch-statement

I am currently developing a text-based RPG in Ruby, however there are some bugs in the programming code. The code is long, so I'll provide a link to the [Source Code HERE](https://github.com/domecraft/Games/blob/master/Text-Games/rpg.rb).

The problem occurs at line 113. Whenever I enter "y" for case randEvent1 it accepts it and does the following lines in the when statement but when I put in "yes", it skips all of those lines goes to the line:

```
puts "Do you want to go to a Tavern next?"
puts "Or maybe you want to go to the forest?"
```

My question is, why does it skip the lines when I put in "yes" for randEvent1 even though I put that it will execute the following the when statement if `randEvent1 == "y" || "yes"`?

This problem also occurs when I put in *"no"* for the case RandEvent1.

Could it be possible it is a problem with doing `||` in a case..when statement? Is the syntax different for the *or* operator in case..when than in if statements?

Comment: When you ask questions about code, you are supposed to summarize the code in your question, so we don't have to chase it down, and to allow your question to make sense if/when the link breaks. Otherwise you're forcing people to spend their time looking up the information needed to answer your question. Remember, everyone is a volunteer, so consuming time needlessly discourages answers. "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case statements do not accept `||` like `if`s do. The proper syntax for a case having two or more possible inputs is `,`. So, instead of doing `case 'y' || 'yes'`, it should be `case 'y', 'yes'`.